# How do I get 'this' in this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

Sorry, my javascript-fu isn't good enough to come up with a better question.

I am using the typeahead feature of bootstrap (bootstrap-typeahead.js) but with the modifications added in by Gudbergur Erlendsson [here](https://gist.github.com/1891669).

I am using the onselect feature and want to manipulate the input that was being typed in in here (really wording this badly I know) like so (using coffeescript);

```
$('form input').typeahead
  source: list
  onselect: (obj) ->
    $(this).css('background-color','blue')
```

Obviously this doesn't work as `this` is not in scope in the onselect function, but how can I get it there? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't `$(obj).css('background-color','blue')` do what you are looking for?

Comment: @Mahn: AFAIK `obj` will be the thing selected, not the `<input>`.

Answer (score 2):

From [the gist](https://gist.github.com/1891669#file_bootstrap_typeahead.js), we see this:

```
var Typeahead = function ( element, options ) {
  this.$element = $(element)
```

and this:

```
select: function () {
  //...
  if (typeof this.onselect == "function")
      this.onselect(val)
```

and this:

```
$.fn.typeahead = function ( option ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        //...
        if (!data) $this.data('typeahead', (data = new Typeahead(this, options)))
```

If you trace through that you'll see that you should have a `this.$element` in your callback so:

```
onselect: (obj) ->
    // AFAIK, 'obj' is the thing you selected
    @$element.css('background-color', 'blue')
```

should be what you're looking for.

Comment: That's a great walkthrough, thanks! You've just driven home how bad my javascript knowledge is. I can't get this to work as you've suggested right now, but I think I may have broken a few other things in my code so I'll keep trying. I really appreciate the effort put in here.

Comment: I seem to have success if I change the select: to have this.onselect(val, this.$element) and my callback to onselect: (obj, elem) -> elem.css('background-color', 'blue')

Comment: @brad: That's interesting, I don't see how that would happen from the code but it wouldn't be the first time code has lied :) What does `console.log(@)` look like in your `onselect` callback? Is there an `@$element` at all?

Answer (score 0):

If `this` is in scope outside of the onselect function but not in scope within the function, do a `that = this` outside the function, then you can refer to `that` instead of `this` within the function. If you're interested, read more about `that` here: [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html)

So for example:

```
that = this
$('form input').typeahead
  source: list
  onselect: (obj) ->
    $(that).css('background-color','blue')
```